# Invoke-WebRequest in docker Entrypoint

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container, azure-container-instances

Docker file -

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./install /src/install
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile c:\\src\\install\\UpdateWindowsService.ps1;"] 
CMD ["C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe", "w3svc"]
```

Powershell file

```
#Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $zipPath -OutFile $destFile
Write-Host "Downloaded File from $zipPath !" -ForegroundColor Yellow;
```

I need powershell file to run on startup so that it will download the latest zip file and further script will proceed with buisness logic But I am getting error while running the docker in container instance.

Error

> Unable to connect remote server

Strangely When I access Docker using `docker exec -it <container-id> powershell` it downloads the zip successfully. Not able to understand where actual problem is.

Comment: Could you post your `docker run` command, please?

Comment: Actually it run by Azure container instance , i am just passing env variables to ARM template

Comment: And even though I run same container on my local machine it works correctly

Comment: Can you try using PSPing (using TCP) to ping some domains, to see if you have an outgoing network traffic at all? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psping

Comment: Question is when I do "docker exec" and download the same zip .. it does .. If there was any issues it would not have run in "docker exec"